# getElementById from an external javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code in a separate javascript file.

```
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");
var three = document.getElementById("three");
var four = document.getElementById("four");
var five = document.getElementById("five");
var oneText = document.getElementById("oneText");
var twoText = document.getElementById("twoText");
var threeText = document.getElementById("threeText");
var fourText = document.getElementById("fourText");
var fiveText = document.getElementById("fiveText");

function buttonClicked() {
console.log('Hello!');
}
```

The javascript file is linked in my HTML file using.

```
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

I put a button in my HTML file with an onclick call of buttonClicked, I have tested it and when the button is pressed it returns 'Hello!' in the javascript console (as I was hoping) but when I try to change one of the elements on the HTML elements I get an error saying.

```
TypeError: one is null
```

I'd like to now if I should be using some import statement or if I should be using inline javascript.

Cheers

Comment: Add `<script src="main.js"></script>` at the end of the page

Comment: The HTML or the Javascript file?

Comment: Put it just before the `</body>` in your HTML.

Comment: Tried it on the HTML file, worked, thx soooo much.

Comment: ..Or place your code into [`onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event handler

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/wGTiYOXZuPBVYAEF1nmC?p=preview see this code it is working so can edit this Plnkr with your code and reproduce that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `SCRIPT` tag that pulls in `main.js` below the HTML tag that has the `one` id. You can think of it as the HTML is converted to DOM by the browser in order. That includes the loading of JavaScript that has references to DOM. If you put the `SCRIPT` tag in the header, it will be parsed and executed in the context of the DOM at that point in time (which will likely not have the element with `one` id). By putting the inclusion of the JavaScript file at the bottom of the page, you avoid needing to do something like the jQuery `$(documnt).ready(...)` -- instead, you force execution to happen when the HTML has been converted to DOM.

Comment: Here is no `jQuery` tag

Comment: @hindmost I know -- I was explaining it in the context of `jQuery.ready` which most JavaScript developers are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is by putting all your code in a `window.onload` function, like this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var one = document.getElementById("one");
    var two = document.getElementById("two");
    var three = document.getElementById("three");
    var four = document.getElementById("four");
    var five = document.getElementById("five");
    var oneText = document.getElementById("oneText");
    var twoText = document.getElementById("twoText");
    var threeText = document.getElementById("threeText");
    var fourText = document.getElementById("fourText");
    var fiveText = document.getElementById("fiveText");

    function buttonClicked() {
        console.log('Hello!');
    }
}
```